# Show text values that are duplicated in multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the data:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
q   w   r   t
c   g   s   g
q   q   q   f   
d   e   b   d       d
t   d   g   r
a   t   d   a   
g   a   l   u       g
```

I need a formula in col F that scans text values in col A and shows only those which repeat in all the four columns from A to D. If the value repeats in three or fewer columns then it must not show up in F.

In the above dataset the `d` and `g` value from col A is present in all columns and is thus shown in F.

Comment: You say you want a formula but you have vba and excel-vba in your tags. So do you want a formula, or are you looking for a formula and vba to put the formula in column F for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values can only occur once per column then either one of these short formulas will do the trick:

```
=REPT(A1,3=COUNTIF(B:D,A1))

or

=IF(3=COUNTIF(B:D,A1),A1,"")
```

But if the values can occur more than once in any column then you will need a slightly longer formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)*COUNTIF(C:C,A1)*COUNTIF(D:D,A1),A1,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

By Formula:

Put this in F1 and copy down:

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,C:C,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,D:D,1,FALSE))=FALSE),A1,"")
```

Comment: Thanks. Your formula works too. I wish I could select multiple answers as best answer.